# Spring MVC Controller: what is the difference between "return forward", "return redirect" and "return jsp file"

Tags: java, spring, http, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

I don't understand what I should use.
I have two pages - intro.jsp(1) and booksList.jsp(2). For each page I created one Controller Class.
The first page has button which opens second page:

```
<form method="GET" action="/request-list">
        <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

**The first question is:** I am not sure about correctness this button. It works well, but I have question mark after press this button.

**The second question is:** When I press that button, method with next annotation is called (Controller for the second page):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/books")
@Controller
public class BooksListController {

   @RequestMapping
   public String booksList() {
      return "jsp/books/booksList";
   }
}
```

What should I return by this method? In other words how can I jump from first page to second one?

1. `return "redirect:/books"; returns http://localhost:8080/books?`
2. `return "jsp/books/booksList"; returns http://localhost:8080/request-list?`
3. `return "forward:/books"; returns http://localhost:8080/request-list?`

I see that result is the same: all these Strings gave me the same page (page 2 was opened).
In which cases I should use "redirect", "forward", "page.jsp"?

Also I've read [Post/Redirect/Get article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get). Do I have to use "redirect" after POST method handling??

Comment: What do you mean "I have question mark after press this button"? Anyway, it was not expected to call /book since you submit /request-list

Comment: There is question mark - returns http://localhost:8080/request-list**?** Also I didn't call /book. I called /books. This page has to show list of books.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

> The first question is: I am not sure about correctness this button. It
>   works well, but I have question mark after press this button.

Ok, it's insert a question mark because you use GET http method. You need to use POST method to pass the data in the request payload.

---

```
return "redirect:/books";
```

It returns to the client (browser) which  interprets the http response and automatically calls the redirect URL

```
return "jsp/books/booksList";
```

It process the JSP and send the HTML to the client

```
return "forward:/books";
```

It transfer the request and calls the URL direct in the server side.

---

To decide which one to use you have to consider some aspects of each approach:

Forward: is faster, the client browser is not involved, the browser displays the original URL, the request is transfered do the forwarded URL.

Redirect: is slower, the client browser is involved, the browser displays the redirected URL, it creates a new request to the redirected URL.

Comment: Thank you, but I know that. I asked - In which cases should I use them?

Comment: As I could understand, I have to use "redirect" after data changing. Am I right?

Comment: Also: forward keeps the request attributes and request parameters. They are passed on behind the scenes to the final handling code.