# Java Spring MVC: After controller forwards, browser shows url from old controller, not url of controller to which it forwards

Tags: java, spring, url, controller, forward

After a successful login, the controller method below forwards to another controller to serve a model and view. This works fines -- but the browser's url shows "http://localhost:8080/AppName/loginSuccessForward" after the forward completes, even though it's displaying the view from the forwarded controller.

Is there a way to get the browser to show the forwarded controller's url? If it's working as I'd like, the user will either see "http://localhost:8080/AppName/l/l/profile" or "http://localhost:8080/AppName/t/t/profile" in the browser, depending on which class of user he or she is.

```
@RequestMapping("/loginSuccessForward")
public String loginForward(Principal principal){
    if (principal == null){
        return "/";
    } else {
        if (user1Service.getUser(principal.getName()) != null){
            return "forward:/t/t/profile";
        } else if (user2Service.getUser(principal.getName()) != null){
            return "forward:/l/l/profile";
        } else {
            return "/";
        }
    }           
}
```

For context: This is built on Spring MVC (though seems like a general Java issue).

Comment: Of course. It's a server-side forward. The client (web browser) is not involved at all. The alternative is to send a *redirect* back to the browser, so *it* can send a new request to the updated URL.

Comment: @Andreas -- Understood, thanks a lot for the explanation. I didn't know that was the distinction between forward: and redirect: prefixes. I'll accept your answer when it unlocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `forward:` to `redirect:`.

See:

- [Spring MVC Controller: what is the difference between “return forward”, “return redirect” and “return jsp file”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28697681/5221149)
- [Why do we use redirect in Spring MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18671463/5221149)