# Difference between returning view name and forwarding to it

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I have simple JSP view - home.jsp and simple controller for handling homepage requests. I wonder what is the difference between these two controller methods:

```
@GetMapping("/")
public String home() {
    return "home.jsp";
}

@GetMapping("/")
public String home() {
    return "forward:home.jsp";
}
```

If I add any attributes to request in first or second example I have access to them in both cases so I guess that internally Spring does exact same thing in both cases. But is there any difference that I can't see? The only case where I see sense in using forward: is when we want to dispatch request to another controller.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28697681/spring-mvc-controller-what-is-the-difference-between-return-forward-return

Comment: I saw this and this does not answer the question. I ask about this exact case and if the first version of my method does something more than second one or vice versa, or they do exact same thing.

Answer (score 1):

My reading of the Spring docs is that there will be no difference compared to returning the JSP view name directly; but that the handling could be different if you were using another view technology.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-redirecting-forward-prefix

I've done a quick test, and it does work for dispatching to other controller methods.